# Trying to update and getting error

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I'm pretty new to ubuntu. Trying to run 
sudo apt-get update
I receive the following error:

```
Ign:1 h.ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 h.ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release               
Ign:3 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Err:4 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6 ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The PPA doesn't have any Bionic files. Follow the PPA's URL and see for yourself.

Comment: If you look at the PPA's main page (https://launchpad.net/~mjblenner/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-hal) you'll note it was last worked on by the owner 2015-December; creating a Xenial (16.04) release prior to 16.04's official release.  You could also open the url as user535733 suggested and navigate to dists/ folder (http://ppa.launchpad.net/mjblenner/ppa-hal/ubuntu/dists/) and you'll see the code names of supported releases.  PPA's are 3rd party repositories of software, you should check the support your release & you trust the authors (they aren't validate by Canonical/Ubuntu)